# Is there an equivalent of the PHP function sanitize_key in Gutenberg?

Tags: javascript, slug, block-editor, id, sanitization

In WordPress's PHP library there is a function [`sanitize_key`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_key/) used to generate database keys and HTML IDs. I'd like to generate a slug from a title that can be used as an HTML ID, from within a Gutenberg block. Is there an equivalent (or close to equivalent) function in the Gutenberg library, or must I make my own?

Comment: The function [`cleanForSlug`](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/f33498b0d6746e64a65a5dbccf31507842bf4e15/packages/editor/src/utils/url.js#L25-L43) in Gutenberg's `url.js` seems to do the job. However I'm not sure if this is available to import into a Gutenberg block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `import { cleanForSlug } from "@wordpress/editor";` in your block.js file to import the function in and then use the it like `cleanForSlug(stringToClean)` to create the ID's.